# ng new does fail to untar some packages

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, angular-cli

I try to create a new Angular2 Application using angular-cli, but can not get it to work properly.

ng new fails during the npm step: Installing packages for tooling via npm

```
Successfully initialized git.
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/istextorbinary/2.1.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/to-fast-properties/1.0.2/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/js-tokens/2.0.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/esutils/2.0.2/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/loose-envify/1.2.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/js-tokens/2.0.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/esutils/2.0.2/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/loose-envify/1.2.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/js-tokens/2.0.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/esutils/2.0.2/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/loose-envify/1.2.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/is-buffer/1.1.4/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/matcher-collection/1.0.4/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/ensure-posix-path/1.0.2/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/fast-ordered-set/1.0.3/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/istextorbinary/2.1.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/istextorbinary/2.1.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/array-to-sentence/1.1.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/core-js/2.4.1/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/core-js/2.4.1/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/source-map/0.4.4/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/graceful-readlink/1.0.1/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/base64-arraybuffer/0.1.5/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/arraybuffer.slice/0.0.6/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/callsite/1.0.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/callsite/1.0.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/lodash._basecopy/3.0.1/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/string.prototype.codepointat/0.2.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/redeyed/1.0.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/wrappy/1.0.2/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/wrappy/1.0.2/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/acorn/1.2.2/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/center-align/0.1.3/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/right-align/0.1.3/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/lcid/1.0.0/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/wordwrap/0.0.2/package.tgz
 untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/npm/2.14.21/package.tgz
EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/var/www/public/angular-2-prova/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/brace-expansion/node_modules/balanced-match/package.json.2223820355'
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/var/www/public/angular-2-prova/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/brace-expansion/node_modules/balanced-match/package.json.2223820355'
    at Error (native)
```

Comment: Which version of the CLI are you using? I don't think it uses Broccoli any more.

Comment: angular-cli: 0.1.0
node: 5.0.0
os: linux x64

Comment: `Angular-cli` has gone a long way since the `0.1.0`. So upgrading both `Node` and `angular-cli` is a must.

Comment: node 5.0.0 is fine... the latest CLI is beta 17, but the other requirement to mention is npm v3+